# How to install LESS on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: css, less, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to install [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) on my system. Can someone tell me how to install `LESS`?

Comment: Ubuntu's dedicated StackExchange site (http://askubuntu.com/) would probably get you the best answers :)

Comment: It's okay to post this kind of question here.

Comment: @YasirAdnan - Sorry, this isn't a programming question and it's off topic, among other things. Check out the [faq] for the list of topics; also, see [Stack Exchange Sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) for the full list of available Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install node-less`

Answer (score 16):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev
git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git
cd node
./configure
make
sudo make install
node -v
```

Now Download NPM, which we'll use to install LESS

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
npm -v
npm install less
```

You've to update the PATH to LESS

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/node_modules/less/bin
source ~/.bashrc
```

You should now be able to invoke LESS from the terminal window like so:

```
lessc LESSFILE.less > CSSFILE.css
```

(Source: [sprResponsive](https://sprresponsive.com/install-less-on-linux/))

Comment: Dead link ----------^

Comment: The npmjs link you have no longer works. The new one is:
[https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh](https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install node-less` seems much simpler

Comment: NPMjs link moved yet again. Use: `curl https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh`